# Horizontally concatenate three 1d arrays of different lengths into one 2d array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, merge, concatenation

Is this possible?

Say I have 3 cell arrays of different lengths in matlab:

```
"hello"
"hi"

"whats"
"your"
"name"

"how"
"are"
"you"
```

and I want to concatenate them into a 2d array:

```
"hello" "whats"  "how"
"hi"    "your"   "are"
 0      "name"   "you"
```

is this possible? I have tried using cat() and horzcat() but obviously because of the different lengths of matrices, it comes up with an error.

Comment: If your cell-strings are variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, adding a `0` pad explicitly is the simplest route: `[[a;0],b,c]`

Answer (score 0):

According to MATLAB's help,

`Concatenating arrays next to one another using commas is called horizontal concatenation. Each array must have the same number of rows. Similarly, when the arrays have the same number of columns, you can concatenate vertically using semicolons.`

So it would be impossible, since your array should have rows of different length.

I think your best option is to use `cell`.